# How to fix auto update array in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

that is suppose to come 1,2,3 but coming 3,3,3, how to fix that ?
Javascript updating automatically

```js
let test = [ { id: 1 } ];
let test2 = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

let x = []

test2.forEach(i => {
  test[0].id = i.id;
  x.push(test[0])
});

console.log(x)
```

Comment: `x.push({ ...test[0] });`

Comment: `test[0]` is a reference to the object at index `0`. After the `.forEach()` `x` has `test2.length` copies of that one reference.

Comment: It's a dupe of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) - in some way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are pushing the same object 3 times and at the end of the loop it will have 3 reference of the same object i.e `test[0]`

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy all properties of object

```js
let test = [{ id: 1 }];
let test2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

let x = [];

test2.forEach((i) => {
  test[0].id = i.id;
  x.push({ ...test[0] });
});

console.log(x);
```

Comment: _"it will have 3 copies of object"_ - If that would be the case then the problem as observed by OP would not exist. `.push(test[0])` pushes references to the object at index `0` and not a copy of the object

Answer (score 1):

Use the spread operator:

```
x.push({ ...test[0] })
```

Basically you need to shallow clone the array because it's an object; `forEach` will create 3 references to the same `test[0]` object at the beginning of the call.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the same reference to the array everytime. You are updating that same value too i.e., `test[0]`.

So in the end, you have an array with three elements, all 3 pointing to the same object whose `id` property you have updated to the final value - `test2[2].id`.

You can directly push in an object with the correct `id` property. You will not need an extra test array as you are creating your object and pushing them on the go.

```js
let test = [ { id: 1 } ];
let test2 = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

let x = []

test2.forEach(i => {
  x.push({ id : i.id })
});

console.log(x)
```